# Gtk main loop and GTask

Tags: c++, gtk, glib

I am newer in GTK and now try to find a explonation of how GTask is working.

1. My main question is how in main thread I can implement a waiting all tasks finished and callbacks called before exit from app?
2. Is it nessesary to call `g_main_loop_run` after `g_task_run_in_thread` and call `g_main_loop_quit` in task callback in each time or not?
3. Is `g_main_loop_run` block a thread until `g_main_loop_quit` called?
4. What is the best way to run many task in one main loop?

Thank you, guys!

My code for test how it is working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
 
typedef GObject myGObj;
static volatile int flag = 0;
GMainLoop *loop;
static int again = 0;


static void
some_blocking_function_async (GTask *task,
                          gpointer object,
                          gpointer task_data,
                          GCancellable *cancellable)
{
    printf("%p: %s\n", g_thread_self(), __func__);
    std::cout << " some_blocking_function_async sleep\n";
    usleep(3000000); //emulate some work
    std::cout << " some_blocking_function_async waked up\n";
    //g_main_loop_quit(loop); //callback no called if loop quited here

    g_task_return_boolean(task, TRUE);
}

static void 
cb_func(GObject *gobject,
                GAsyncResult *res,
                gpointer      user_data)
{
    printf("%p: %s\n", g_thread_self(), __func__);
    std::cout << "cb_func sleep\n";
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "cb_func waked up\n";
    flag++;
    GTask *task = (GTask*)user_data;

    g_main_loop_quit(loop); //task don't call a calback if main loop not quited and runned again  ???

    if(flag == 1 && again == 0){
        again++;
        std::cout << "Run 2nd Task\n";
        GTask* task2 = g_task_new(NULL, NULL, cb_func, NULL);
        g_task_run_in_thread(task2, some_blocking_function_async);
        g_object_unref(task2);

        g_main_loop_run(loop); //task don't call a calback if main loop not quited and runned again  ???
    }
}

int main(int, char**){
    printf("%p: %s\n", g_thread_self(), __func__);
    std::cout << "Hello, from testGt!\n";

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    GTask* task = g_task_new(NULL, NULL, cb_func, NULL);
    g_task_run_in_thread(task, some_blocking_function_async);
    std::cout << "Task runned, from testGt!\n";
    g_object_unref(task);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    std::cout << "Loop runned, from testGt!\n";

    while(flag != 2){
        std::cout << "Sleep, from testGt!\n";
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "Wakeup, from testGt!\n";
    }

    g_main_loop_quit(loop);

    std::cout << flag << " Bye, from testGt!\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0x564375b85c00: main
Hello, from testGt!
Task runned, from testGt!
0x564375b68b60: some_blocking_function_async
 some_blocking_function_async sleep
 some_blocking_function_async waked up
0x564375b85c00: cb_func
cb_func sleep
cb_func waked up
Run 2nd Task
0x564375b68b60: some_blocking_function_async
 some_blocking_function_async sleep
 some_blocking_function_async waked up
0x564375b85c00: cb_func
cb_func sleep
cb_func waked up
Loop runned, from testGt!
2 Bye, from testGt!
```

---

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(testGt VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(testGt main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testGt ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${GTK_LIBRARIES})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Your question is not about `gtk` but the `glib` stuff. Take a look on what is an Event Driven Architecture in programming. It's unclear what do you expect to be done here ; understand `g_main_loop_run` as a thread itself. A nice explanation on how it works could be read [there](https://developer-old.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en) and some examples [here](http://devlib.symbian.slions.net/s3/GUID-7FD05006-09C1-4EF4-A2EB-AD98C2FA8866.html) ; lot of Q/A on SO too ...

Comment: My C compiler can't compile this code tagged with.

Comment: @273K I use C++, added CMakeLists for u

Comment: You tagged it with C, you supposed to use C.

Comment: @273k First tag is C++, it is supposed C++ to be used ) And let's focus on questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really a glib/gio expert but, I may be able to give some tips.

1. You have a few options there, you could call `g_task_get_completed` on the tasks you spawn to check if they are done but, as you are spawning them from the callback, you'd need to accumulate the tasks spawned in a mutex protected vector for example.
2. You only need to call `g_main_loop_run` if you want your app to run indefinitely until quit is called otherwise, if you have your own loop already, you need to "drive" glib's loop with `g_main_context_iteration`.
3. Yes, `g_main_loop_run` will always block
4. You can create the tasks in a loop and glib will take care of driving them.

Here is a changed version of your code that drives glib's loop inside the while statement

```
--- old.cpp 2023-07-20 09:34:13
+++ a.cpp   2023-07-20 09:34:55
@@ -4,7 +4,6 @@
 
 typedef GObject myGObj;
 static volatile int flag = 0;
-GMainLoop *loop;
 static int again = 0;
 
 static void
\ No newline at end of file
@@ -32,10 +31,7 @@
     usleep(1000000);
     std::cout << "cb_func waked up\n";
     flag++;
-    GTask *task = (GTask *)user_data;
 
-    g_main_loop_quit(loop); // task don't call a calback if main loop not quited and runned again  ???
-
     if (flag == 1 && again == 0)
     {
         again++;
\ No newline at end of file
@@ -43,8 +39,6 @@
         GTask *task2 = g_task_new(NULL, NULL, cb_func, NULL);
         g_task_run_in_thread(task2, some_blocking_function_async);
         g_object_unref(task2);
-
-        g_main_loop_run(loop); // task don't call a calback if main loop not quited and runned again  ???
     }
 }
 
\ No newline at end of file
@@ -53,25 +47,24 @@
     printf("%p: %s\n", g_thread_self(), __func__);
     std::cout << "Hello, from testGt!\n";
 
-    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
+    auto loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
+    auto context = g_main_loop_get_context(loop);
 
     GTask *task = g_task_new(NULL, NULL, cb_func, NULL);
     g_task_run_in_thread(task, some_blocking_function_async);
     std::cout << "Task runned, from testGt!\n";
     g_object_unref(task);
 
-    g_main_loop_run(loop);
     std::cout << "Loop runned, from testGt!\n";
 
     while (flag != 2)
     {
         std::cout << "Sleep, from testGt!\n";
+        g_main_context_iteration(context, FALSE);
         usleep(1000000);
         std::cout << "Wakeup, from testGt!\n";
     }
 
-    g_main_loop_quit(loop);
-
     std::cout << flag << " Bye, from testGt!\n";
 
     return 0;
\ No newline at end of file
```

On this code, you will see that it drives the tasks every time `g_main_context_iteration` is called, and when you achieve the desired number of ran tasks, it will just move out and finish the program.